# Filter only links in a dataframe based on certain domain name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a pandas dataframe having 5 columns. I need to filter the dataframe on the column `link` based on a domain name in a list and count the number of rows for each process repetitively.
Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
url_id | link
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      | http://www.example.com/somepath
2      | http://www.somelink.net/example
3      | http://other.someotherurls.ac.uk/thisissomelink.net&part/sample 
4      | http://part.example.com/directory/files
```

I want to filter the dataframe based on a domain name from the list below and count the number of each result:

```
domains = ['example.com', 'other.com', 'somelink.net' , 'sample.com']
```

Following is the expected output:

```
domain       | no_of_links
--------------------------
example.com  |  2
other.com    |  0
somelink.net |  1
sample.com   |  0
```

This is my code:

```
from tld import get_tld 
import pandas as pd

def urlparsing(row):
    url = row['link']
    res = get_tld(url,as_object=True)
    return (res.fld)

link = ({"url_id":[1,2,3,4],"link":["http://www.example.com/somepath",
            "http://www.somelink.net/example",
            "http://other.someotherurls.ac.uk/thisissomelink.net&part/sample",
            "http://part.example.com/directory/files"]})

domains = ['example.com', 'other.com', 'somelink.net' , 'sample.com']
df_link = pd.DataFrame(link)

ref_dom = []
for dom in domains:   
    ddd = df_link[(df_link.apply(lambda row: urlparsing(row), axis=1)).str.contains(dom, regex=False)]     
    ref_dom.append([dom, len(ddd)])

pd.DataFrame(ref_dom, columns=['domain','no_of_links'])
```

Basically, my code is working. However, when the size of the dataframe is very big (more than 5 millions rows), and the list of the domain name is more than a hundred thousand, the process takes my day.
If you have an alternative way to make it faster, please let me know. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using regex and findall function of df.str function

```py
domains = ['example.com', 'other.com', 'somelink.net' , 'sample.com']
pat = "|".join([f"http[s]?://(?:\w*\.)?({domain})" 
                 for domain in map(lambda x: x.replace(".","\."), domains)])
match = df["link"].str.findall(pat).explode().explode()
match = match[match.str.len()>0]
match.groupby(match).count()
```

**result**

```py
link
example.com     2
somelink.net    1
Name: link, dtype: int64
```

**For Pandas Before 0.25**

```py
domains = ['example.com', 'other.com', 'somelink.net' , 'sample.com']
pat = "|".join([f"http[s]?://(?:\w*\.)?({domain})" 
                 for domain in map(lambda x: x.replace(".","\."), domains)])

match = df["link"].str.findall(pat) \
.apply(lambda x: "".join([domain for match in x for domain in match]).strip())

match = match[match.str.len()>0]
match.groupby(match).count()
```

to get domains with 0 links also you can join the result with df having all domain